# Save multiple docker images using one command

Tags: linux, bash, docker, terminal

Currently I am exporting docker images using below command

> `docker save imageName | gzip > imageName.tar.gz`

> `docker save mysql | gzip > mysql.tar.gz`

This command working fine for single image, i have tons of docker images in my local system, want to export.
but i don't know how to export all images which is available in `docker images`.

Please guide me how can i archive this by single command. which will save all images in current directory respectively *ImageNames*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
docker save imageName1:tag1 imageName2:tag2 ... imageNameN:tagN | gzip > images.tar.gz
```

if you need to get all images, you might use something like this (but it might be getting a little too much, so be careful):

```sh
docker save $( \
    docker images \
        --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' \
        --filter "dangling=false" \
    | grep -v image_that_i_dont_want ) \
| gzip > images.tar.gz
```

EDIT:

in the event you need to save all images on a system in separate files:

```sh
for img in $( docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' --filter "dangling=false" ) ; do
    base=${img#*/}
    docker save "$img" | gzip > "${base//:/__}".tar.gz
done
```

Comment: This saves everything in a single tarball. I guess the OP would like one file per image.

Comment: it might be but it wastes more space

Comment: What if you working on area where you have very limited internet bandwidth & speed? @Stefano

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is to use the first approach and create one single tar file. Split the resulting file in smaller chunks, send it over and rebuild the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script, these two scripts will help you save and load docker images, If you have too many images, I think these scripts will help you.
Script to save docker  images is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#files will be saved in the dir 'Docker_images'
mkdir Docker_images
cd Docker_images
directory=`pwd`
c=0
#save the image names in 'list.txt'
doc= docker images | awk '{print $1}' > list.txt
printf "START \n"
input="$directory/list.txt"
#Check and create the image tar for the docker images
while IFS= read -r line
do
     one=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
     two=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 1-3`
     if [ "$one" != "<none>" ]; then
             c=$((c+1))
             printf "\n $one \n $two \n"
             docker save -o $two$c'.tar' $one
             printf "Docker image number $c successfully converted:   $two$c \n \n"
     fi
done < "$input"
```

Script to load docker images is:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd Docker_images/
directory=`pwd`
ls | grep tar > files.txt
c=0
printf "START \n"
input="$directory/files.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
     c=$((c+1))
     printf "$c) $line \n"
     docker load -i $line
     printf "$c) Successfully created the Docker image $line  \n \n"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: This contains a number of shell programming antipatterns and what looks like coding mistakes. Please review at http://shellcheck.net/ though it probably won't warn about the weird `doc=` line for example.

Comment: Attemted to remove `shell programming anti-patterns` . @tripleee

Comment: The shell already knows which directory you are in, so you don't need `pwd` here. [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The use of temporary files is extremely suspicious. You need to [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)